# clearing UITextField if inputed value exceeds a specified integer

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im looking to see if the inputed value into a UITextField exceeds 100. 
I am using the textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: (code below) to limit the inputed character length to 3. Im wondering if there is a way  piggyback on this method to clear the input if it exceeds a value of 100.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    return !([newString length] >3);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that what you want is to clear the UITextField as soon as the value of 100 is input into it. `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` is a method that works to prevent input, not deal with it in real time. Unfortunately, UITextField does not have a delegate method titled TextFieldDidChange so we are going to have to make one.

Step 1: use UIControl methods to track the message of the textField in real time.

```
[myTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(UITextFieldDidChange) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Step 2: create the UITextFieldDidChange: method

```
-(void)UITextFieldDidChange:(UITextField*)textField{
    NSString *text = textField.text;
    double input = [text doubleValue];
    if (input > 100){
        textField.text = @"";
    }
}
```

Comment: Not to be a bad SO citizen here, but how was my answer not the accepted answer as this individual posted much later than me, and while correct, it is exactly the same as I posted, and doesn't even show you how to do keyboard validation.

Answer (score 3):

You have the textField, so you can just write

```
if([newString length] > 3]) {
textField.text = @"";
}

return YES;
```

EDIT:

It seems what you actually wanted was input validation AND checking for numbers > 100, which you should clarify next time in your question as it was ambiguous.

1.) Validate input is a number

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField*)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString*)string {
      NSCharacterSet* numberSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."];
      return ([string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:numberSet].length == 0);
}
```

2.) Connect "Editing Changed" Action of UITextField to this method via IB or code

```
- (IBAction)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField*)textField {
    NSString* text = textField.text;
    double number = [text doubleValue];

    if(number > 100)
         textField.text = @"";
}
```

3.) Add this code when the textfield is setup to connect it to the method

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't check the input value of the textField.

Comment: What if the user enters 64.3? or 0052? Might be better check the actual value instead of it's length.

Comment: Users can only input whole integers since the input keyboard is a numeric keyboard.

Comment: You didn't ask for code that does validation. Only to limit the inputed character length to 3.

Comment: @TheM00s3 A user can paste any text into the text field regardless of the keyboard type your specify. Or the user can use an external keyboard. Never assume a user can only type on the on-screen keyboard.

Comment: Would setting up a addTarget:action:forControlEvent: on the specific textField and than writing a custom method (void)textFieldDidChange: with the same logic as your method also work?